# rotate on mouse hover

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this function but there are two issues I can't solve, first one is that the mouse action is set on all the screen and I want it to be when hover over the dive "ehab" only, not when I move mouse over screen, 
the other issue is that when I have more than one div , the function works only on the first one ... 
kindly advise me

```
    /*
        By     : Ofelquis
        Twitter: @felquis
        Blog   : tutsmais.com.br

        Simples implementação ;)
    */
    !(function ($doc, $win) {
        var screenWidth = $win.screen.width / 2,
            screenHeight = $win.screen.height / 2,
            $ehab = $doc.querySelectorAll('#ehab')[0],
            validPropertyPrefix = '',
            otherProperty = 'perspective(600px)';

            if(typeof $ehab.style.webkitTransform == 'string') {
                validPropertyPrefix = 'webkitTransform';
            } else {
                if (typeof $ehab.style.MozTransform == 'string') {
                    validPropertyPrefix = 'MozTransform';
                }
            }

        $doc.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
            // vars 
            var centroX     = e.clientX - screenWidth,
                centroY     = screenHeight - (e.clientY + 13),
                degX   = centroX * 0.1,
                degY   = centroY * 0.1

            // Seta o rotate do elemento
            $ehab.style[validPropertyPrefix] = otherProperty + 'rotateY('+ degX +'deg)  rotateX('+ degY +'deg)';
        });
    })(document, window);
```

Comment: "the mouse action is set on all the screen and I want it to be when hover over the dive "ehab" only" - that's because you did `$doc.addEventListener`. If you want to set it on a specific element, use `$ehab` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first problem, (*I want it to be when hover the div "#ehab"*), you need the attach the `mousemove` event to your div:

```
$ehab.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
     //You code here.
});
```

The second problem, (*when I have more than one div , the function works only on the first one*), you can't have duplicated IDs on your DOM tree, change the selector to a class, for example, `.ehab` then you have to loop through the matched elements, please try this code:

```js
/*
                By     : Ofelquis
                Twitter: @felquis
                Blog   : tutsmais.com.br

                Simples implementação ;)
            */
    !(function($doc, $win) {
      var $ehabDIVs = $doc.querySelectorAll('.ehab'),
        otherProperty = 'perspective(600px)';


      for (var i = 0; i < $ehabDIVs.length; ++i) {
        var $ehab = $ehabDIVs[i];

        $ehab.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
          // vars 
          var centroX = (e.pageX - this.offsetLeft) - this.offsetWidth/2,
            centroY = this.offsetHeight/2 - (e.pageY-this.offsetTop),
            degX = centroX * 0.1,
            degY = centroY * 0.1
          if(this._leave) clearInterval(this._leave);
          // Seta o rotate do elemento
          this.style.transform = otherProperty + 'rotateY(' + degX + 'deg)  rotateX(' + degY + 'deg)';
        });

        $ehab.addEventListener('mouseleave', function(e) {
          var self = this;
          this._leave = setTimeout(function() {
              self.style.transform = 'rotateY(0deg)  rotateX(0deg)';
          }, 250);
        });

      }
    })(document, window);
```

```css
.ehab {
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background-color:red;
  margin:15px;
  float:left;
  transition: transform 0.15s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="ehab">First Div</div><div class="ehab">Second Div</div>
```

Good Luck Ismaiel.

Comment: and I will leave this part as it is 

screenWidth = $win.screen.width / 2,
            screenHeight = $win.screen.height / 2,

 ?

Comment: It depends on your aim.

Comment: kindly check this page Ismail,
http://www.hungryminds.be/#-work


the function is working on mouse hove the div only not the full screen, and it works on all other div with same name

Comment: Here you go check out the updated answer! I love this effect, especially on the website ;) I hope you make something as cool in your project good luck.

Comment: thank you Ismail, it's working great as a function, but it looks like a flat perspective, and it doesn't finish smooth when I remove mouse hover

Comment: Yes check out the updated answer I've added smooth mouseleave !

Comment: kindly check it here, it flips now !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :)
http://www.flexsign.tatweereg.com/